# URL in background with out using webview in android?

Tags: android

How to load/run URL in background without making use of **webview** height=0 & width =0 in android?
(I want to open a URL in which the URL should be running in background without opening any of the browser and not even making use of webview)

Comment: Your question is unclear can you explain more about it **BTW** Read this **[How to ask a smart question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question)**

Comment: Use `VISIBILITY` factor. And set it to `VISIBLE`  `onPageFinished()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsoup` library.
https://jsoup.org/

Hope this will help you. I use this library for this kind of requirements.